# Problem outputting sorted list to new file

Tags: python

I am reading a file line by line, sorting the values alphabetically and outputting the sorted results to a new file. In the new file, 2 of the results always appear in a line together.

**The code:**

```
with open("friends.txt", "r") as input_file:
    all_lines = input_file.readlines()

all_lines.sort()

with open("sortedfriends.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in all_lines:
        output_file.write(line)
```

**Contents of unsorted file (friends.txt):**
Amanda
Joe
Samuel
Mary
John
Eve

**Expected result file (sortedfriends.txt):**
Amanda
Eve
Joe
John
Mary
Samuel

**The result I'm getting instead:**
Amanda
EveJoe
John
Mary
Samuel

*Notice how Eve and Joe are on the same line.*

Comment: And that's why you don't omit newline at end of file.

Comment: `Eve` is the last line in the input file and obviously it lacks lineendng. Fix your input file.

Comment: I got the example from a book so I wasn't sure what was wrong. Adding a new line at the end of the file did the trick. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, your input file format is not (it does not end with a "\n").

**Solution 1:** You can manually append a new line to the end of file if you can.

**Solution 2:**

```
with open("friends.txt", "r") as input_file:
    all_lines = input_file.readlines()

# append "\n" to the last element of the list
all_lines[len(all_lines) - 1] += "\n"
all_lines.sort()

# continue code here
```

Comment: Yeah the issue was that I created the file manually. I'll keep this one in mind. Thank you for your help. :D

Answer (score 0):

The real data of all_lines is

```py
all_lines = ["Amanda\n", "Joe\n", "Samuel\n", "Mary\n", "John\n", "Eve"]
```

Notice that `"Eve"` doesn't end with `\n`.

`output_file.write(line)` just write each line content **without endline**, so `"Eve"` isn't written with endline, so next string (`"Joe"`) isn't moved to new line.

Here is how to fix:

```py
all_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in input_line.readlines()]  # remove trailing \n
all_lines.sort()

with open(...) as output_file:
    for line in all_lines:
        output_file.write(line + "\n")  # write with \n
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.

Comment: Why `strip` "\n" from everywhere and then append "\n" later? What if the file is a million lines long? Instead, you can simply append "\n" to the last element of the list.

Comment: @HarshalParekh You can split that line to 2 write. It may be ok.

Comment: This is an inefficient solution. It makes no sense to strip "\n" and then append it later.

Comment: You may use the string without endline, and you can use write 2 times. Is it ok?